# Cordova local notification play sound don't working on IOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

I using cordova local notification for alarm play sound.

```
var sound = '../Library/NoCloud/CryOnMyShoulder.wav';

          cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 1,
                title: 'Scheduled with delay',
                text: 'Test Message 1',
                at: _5_sec_from_now,
                sound: sound,
                badge: 12
            });
```

I try "sound" variable with

1. '../Library/NoCloud/CryOnMyShoulder.wav'
2. 'file://../Library/NoCloud/CryOnMyShoulder.wav'
3. cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'CryOnMyShoulder.wav'

=> Sound don't working, notify is showing in notify center but haven't sound.
Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Could you inspect the app in safari web inspector and post the error trace if any?

Comment: I think there is a problem with iOS and sound in Cordova at the moment. Certainly the normal media plugin needs a work around. (https://github.com/spudmashmedia/cordova-plugin-media/commit/946ffcf569cbaa22241e8ec00f11b4a52a0c6809) and (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10723).